# how say to proguard not obfuscate class and method names when exception occured?

Tags: android, exception, proguard

for exception handling, I put try-catch in all methods of my application and in the catch I send stackTrace of exception to server to find out which class and method has an exception. when I use proguard, class and method names changes and I can't find the exception point, how can I use proguard and also have information about exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Decode obfuscated stack traces you need the mapping.txt that Proguard generate after obfuscation.

Here you can find more information:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding

Answer (score 0):

Mattia is right but it's kind of annoying to implement.
The only tool i'm aware of that does that easily for you is [crashlytics](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/proguard-dexguard)